# How to increase the cell size for annotation in Seaborn heatmap

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, heatmap, seaborn

I'd like to plot `66x66` confusion matrix with `min=0` and `max=15075` (shared [here](https://pastebin.com/vgDAufDP)). Since I'd like to annotate the cells, I am using `annot=True`. But I can't seem to fit the values in the cell even after trying approaches suggested in other stack overflow posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127920/overlapping-yticklabels-is-it-possible-to-control-cell-size-of-heatmap-in-seabo), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275719/seaborn-heatmap-reducing-cell-size) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104322/auto-adjust-font-size-in-seaborn-heatmap). This is my current code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred) # please load the data from the pastebin [link above][1]

# get the tick label font size
fontsize_pt = 10 # plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] does not return a numeric value like suggested [here][2], so I set it to '10'
dpi = 72.27

# comput the matrix height in points and inches
matrix_height_pt = fontsize_pt * conf_mat.shape[0]
matrix_height_in = matrix_height_pt / dpi

# compute the required figure height 
top_margin = 0.04
bottom_margin = 0.04
figure_height = matrix_height_in / (1 - top_margin - bottom_margin)

# build the figure instance with the desired height
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, figure_height),
                       gridspec_kw=dict(top=(1-top_margin), bottom=bottom_margin))

# here, I turned on annot and changed the color map scheme
ax = sns.heatmap(conf_mat, ax=ax, annot=True, cmap="cubehelix")
```

When I run the above code, it returns a figure that looks like this

[image]

I would like the annotated figures to fit in each cell of the heatmap, and if possible, the color range to be a bit more reasonable (instead of all being black as it is right now).

Any suggestion for improvement would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How would you envision the large numbers to fit the cells? `15000` will take quite some horizontal space, so all cells need to be ~4 times wider. Is that what you want?

Comment: @hitzg Yes. If I'd like to make the cells 4x wider, what should I do? Do I multiply `matrix_height_pt` in the code above by `4`? Thank you.

Comment: @yes, I guess that could work. have you tried?

Comment: @hitzg Yes,  I did...but didn't work.

Comment: @user1330974 did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @EveEdomenko, Unfortunately, no...I gave up. If you end up figuring out a way, please share as a solution below and I'd like to learn. Thank you.